# All irreducible polynoms of degree 4 in $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I need to find all irreducible polynoms of degree at most 4 in $\mathbb{Z}_2$

This is my result:

$$ x^4 + x^1 + 1 \\
x^4 + x^2 + 1\\
x^4 + x^3 + 1  \\
x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x^1 + 1 \\
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Degree *at most* $4$ you mean?

Comment: Yes, I've edited this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^4 + x^2 + 1= (x^2 + x + 1)^2$ is not irreducible.

An irreducible polynomial of degree $4$ defines a field extension of $\mathbb Z_2$ of degree $4$. Its $2^4$ elements are the roots of $x^{2^4}-x$ because of Lagrange's theorem in group theory.

Therefore, the irreducible polynomials of degree $4$ are those that divide $x^{2^4}-x$ over $\mathbb Z_2$:
$$
x^{16}-x=x (x + 1) (x^2 + x + 1) (x^4 + x + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
$$
and so there are exactly three of them.

To factor $x^{16}-x$, factor $x^{15}-1$, starting with the factorization into [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial):
$$
x^{16}-x = x(x^{15}-1)=x \Phi_1(x) \Phi_3(x) \Phi_5(x) \Phi_{15}(x) 
$$
which gives
$$
x^{16}-x = x(x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) (x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1)
$$
We then need to further factor these mod 2. The last factor is the only one that is reducible.

Comment: Please explain why $x^{2^4}$!

Comment: You are more than welcome to explain  [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547821/how-do-you-factorize-a-polynom-in-mathbbz-2/2547846?noredirect=1#comment5259933_2547846) how you factorized $x^{16}-x$.