# How do you factorize a polynom in $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How can you efficiently factorize a polynom (in $\mathbb{Z}_2$) ?

Example [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545873/all-irreducible-polynoms-of-degree-4-in-mathbbz-2?answertab=votes#tab-top):

$$x^{16}-x=x (x + 1) (x^2 + x + 1) (x^4 + x + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$$
How do you do this by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the factorization of  $x^{15}-1$ into [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial):
$$
x^{16}-x = x(x^{15}-1)=x \Phi_1(x) \Phi_3(x) \Phi_5(x) \Phi_{15}(x) 
$$
which gives
$$
x^{16}-x = x(x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) (x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1)
$$
We then need to further factor these mod 2. The last factor is the only one that is reducible. Guessing a factorization into two quartics works.

Comment: What do you mean with your last sentence?

Comment: @user1511417. writing the degree-8 factor as the product of two factors of the form $(x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

We know that $x-1 =x+1$, so we have:

\begin{eqnarray}
x^{16}-x &=& x(x^{15}-1)\\
&=& x(x^5-1)\underbrace{(x^{10}+x^5+1)}_{p(x)}\\
&=& x(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)p(x)\\
\end{eqnarray}

Now we have to factor somehow $p(x)$...

Comment: The values of $x^2$ and $x$ coincide in $\Bbb Z_2$, but they are not the same objects. You can't replace $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ by $x^4+x^3+1$. If you could, then there would be an easier way to factorize $x^{16}-x$:
$$x^{16}-x=x-x=0.$$

Comment: I know that $2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But I didn't know, that $x^2 = x$. Why is that?

Comment: Yes $x-1=x+1$, since $2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $0$ and $1$ each time till you find all irreducible linear factors. For example $P(x)=x^{16}-x$ has $P(0)=P(1)=0,$ therefore $x$ and $x-1$ are factors of $P.$ Now $P(x)=x(x-1)Q(x)$ for some $Q(x)\in\Bbb{Z}_2[x].$ Use long division to find $Q$ and apply the same method to find linear factors of $Q.$

Suppose at some point we have no linear factors, then we have to look at irreducible quadratic polynomials of $\Bbb{Z}_2[x].$ There is only one such polynomial and namely it is $x^2+x+1.$ Divide each even degree $(\ge 4)$ factor of $P$ to find all its irreducible quadratic factors.

Again at some point we will ran out of irreducible quadratic factors, then look for irreducible cubic factors (namely) $x^3+x^2+1,$ $ x^3+x+1$ and so on.
Continue this until we have the complete factorization.

**EDIT:**
To find the irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x],$ we can observe that they are of the form $x^n+h(x)+1,$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial of $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ of degree less than on equal to $n-1$ without a constant term and containing odd number of monomials.
For example irreducible bi-quadratic polynomials are given by $h(x)\in\{x^3+x^2+x, x^3, x\}.$

Comment: Why this: $P(0)=P(1)=0 \Rightarrow  x$ and $x-1$ are factors of $P$ ?

Comment: @user1511417: [Fator theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)

Comment: But $x^{16}-x : x^2-x = 1 +\frac{ x^{14}}{x^2-x}$

Comment: No it is $\dfrac{x^{15}-1}{x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{14}x^k.$

Comment: This confuses me even more. What is going on here?

Comment: $x^{16}-x=x(x^{15}-x)$ and rest is a result of polynomial long division (or synthetic division).